# No reaction on service mysql start, init script works

Tags: server, mysql, upstart, database

After upgrading Ubuntu from 12.04 to 13.10, the MySQL server (now 5.5) does not start/stop with `service mysql start|stop`. When typing `/etc/init.d/mysql start`, everything works fine.

Once it does nothing, when pressing ^C and retrying it says:

> start: Job is already running: mysql

while it is not.

After trying to start the service with the upstart syntax, I took a look into the `htop` statuses:

> 19973 root       20   0  2272   552   480 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/service mysql restart
>   19979 root       20   0  6280  1064   936 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 stop mysql

and it stays like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

or:

```
sudo service mysql stop && sleep 3s && sudo service mysql start
```

or again:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: I am `root`. All of these commands don't run, but show an empty newline.